# Can not export png with Amcharts4 by use export API

Tags: amcharts4

I according to the amcharts4 export demo with the export API but it not work. I open the develop tools in the google browser, then i find the blob:https:// is get 200 response after click the export button every time. But it has nothing after the blob:https:// show 200 response.
First i think is will be our app has some policy or else, but the amcharts3 is work fine in our app. So what is the reason for amcharts4 exporting?
Code on blew:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSvx9.png)

Blew is the display in the develop tool when click the export button.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdqqt.png)

BTW, we use the enterprise version.